# Login To Google account (Web page, not REST API) using access token

Tags: c#, selenium, google-account

I would like to login to Google Account automatically using tools similar to Selenium (Google blocking this tool). I was thinking about getting some kind of token using REST API then using this token in web page url (for example: google.com/?logmeinPlease=[TOKEN])

I searched through web, but I couldn't find any solutions to my issue.
Your help will be gladly appreciated,
Thank you,
Yulia

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `https://accounts.google.com/signin` in any case google has many products with API access available, so it really depends on what's the goal you're trying to achieve - logging in to youtube? gmail?

Comment: currently when I'm trying to automate sign in from browser, google asking me for phone verification, I would like to know if it's possible to get token from REST API and then use it to login from browser in order to skip phone verification.

Comment: this has all the details https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in